# Gatsby/React navigator

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

Hello I'm currently into an issue where I want to show a pop up using JS in my react component but I'm encountering an error when building my gatsby. WebpackError: ReferenceError: navigator is not defined. Here is my JS code that I will use on my React component.

JS

```
var isMobile = {
Android: function () {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
  },
  iOS: function () {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)
  },
  Windows: function () {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i)
  },
  any: function () {
    return isMobile.Android() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Windows()
  },
}

if (!isMobile.any()) {
  $('body').addClass('is-not-ios')
  $('.show-ios, .show-android').addClass('disabled')
  $('.show-no-device').removeClass('disabled')
}

if (isMobile.Android()) {
  $('body').addClass('is-not-ios')
  $('head').append('<meta name="theme-color" content="#FFFFFF"> />')
  $('.show-android').removeClass('disabled')
  $(
    '.show-ios, .show-no-device, .simulate-android, .simulate-iphones'
  ).addClass('disabled')
}

if (isMobile.iOS()) {
  $('body').addClass('is-ios')
  $('.show-ios').removeClass('disabled')
  $(
    '.show-android, .show-no-device, .simulate-android, .simulate-iphones'
  ).addClass('disabled')
}

if (pwaEnabled === true) {
  //Setting Timeout Before Prompt Shows Again if Dismissed
  var now = new Date()
  var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0)
  var diff = now - start
  var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
  var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay)
  var dismissDate = localStorage.getItem('Appkit-PWA-Timeout-Value')

  if (day - dismissDate > pwaRemind) {
    localStorage.removeItem('Appkit-PWA-Prompt')
  }

  //Dismiss Prompt Button
  $('.pwa-dismiss').on('click', function () {
    console.log('User Closed Add to Home / PWA Prompt')
    localStorage.setItem('Appkit-PWA-Prompt', 'install-rejected')
    $('body')
      .find('#menu-install-pwa-android, #menu-install-pwa-ios, .menu-hider')
      .removeClass('menu-active')
    localStorage.setItem('Appkit-PWA-Timeout-Value', day)
  })

  //Detecting Mobile Operating Systems
  var isMobile = {
    Android: function () {
      return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
    },
    iOS: function () {
      return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)
    },
    any: function () {
      return isMobile.Android() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Windows()
    },
  }
  var isInWebAppiOS = window.navigator.standalone == true
  var isInWebAppChrome = window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches

  //Trigger Install Prompt for Android
  if (isMobile.Android()) {
    function showInstallPrompt() {
      if ($('#menu-install-pwa-android, .add-to-home').length) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('Appkit-PWA-Prompt') != 'install-rejected') {
          setTimeout(function () {
            $('.add-to-home').addClass(
              'add-to-home-visible add-to-home-android'
            )
            $('#menu-install-pwa-android, .menu-hider').addClass('menu-active')
          }, 4500)
          console.log('Triggering PWA Window for Android')
        } else {
          console.log(
            'PWA Install Rejected. Will Show Again in ' +
              (dismissDate - day + pwaRemind) +
              ' Days'
          )
        }
      } else {
        console.log(
          'The div #menu-install-pwa-android was not found. Please add this div to show the install window'
        )
      }
    }
    let deferredPrompt
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      deferredPrompt = e
      showInstallPrompt()
    })
    $('.pwa-install').on('click', function (e) {
      deferredPrompt.prompt()
      deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
        if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
          //console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
        } else {
          //console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
        }
        deferredPrompt = null
      })
    })
    window.addEventListener('appinstalled', (evt) => {
      $('#menu-install-pwa-android, .menu-hider').removeClass('menu-active')
    })
  }

  //Trigger Install Guide iOS
  if (isMobile.iOS()) {
    if (!isInWebAppiOS) {
      if ($('#menu-install-pwa-ios, .add-to-home').length) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('Appkit-PWA-Prompt') != 'install-rejected') {
          console.log('Triggering PWA Window for iOS')
          setTimeout(function () {
            $('.add-to-home').addClass('add-to-home-visible add-to-home-ios')
            $('#menu-install-pwa-ios, .menu-hider').addClass('menu-active')
          }, 4500)
        } else {
          console.log(
            'PWA Install Rejected. Will Show Again in ' +
              (dismissDate - day + pwaRemind) +
              ' Days'
          )
        }
      } else {
        console.log(
          'The div #menu-install-pwa-ios was not found. Please add this div to show the install window'
        )
      }
    }
  }
}

const loadScript = () => window.addEventListener('load', () => isMobile())

export default loadScript
```

And here is my component where I'll be using the `loadScript`

```
const MasterIndexPage = () => {

useEffect(() => {
loadScript()
  }, [])

<div
      id="menu-video"
      className="menu menu-box-bottom rounded-m"
      data-menu-height="410"
      data-menu-effect="menu-over"
    >
      <div class="responsive-iframe max-iframe">
        <iframe
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qCSBMbUa9jg"
          frameborder="0"
          allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
      </div>
      <div className="menu-title">
        <p className="color-highlight">Learn</p>
        <h1>How to install</h1>
        <a href="#" className="close-menu">
          <i className="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="content mt-n2">
        <p>Install Sparkle</p>
        <a
          href="#"
          className="close-menu btn btn-full btn-m shadow-l rounded-s text-uppercase font-600 bg-green-dark mt-n2"
        >
          Done
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
}
```

Can anyone help me on what is the problem? This is my expected output when I'm using only full JS.

[image]

This will prompt whenever I load the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm encountering an error when building my gatsby

Summarizing and simplifying, `gatsby develop` is interpreted directly by the client (browser) using a web socket (that's why you have instant refresh) and there's a `window` or `navigator` object, while `gatsby build` is handled by the Node server, where obviously [there's no `window`, `document` or other global objects (like `navigator`)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) because they are not even defined yet.

It's a quite common and straight-forward issue in Gatsby that can be easily bypassed by adding the following condition:

```
typeof window !== `undefined`
```

If the window object is defined, means that you are not in the build-time process so you can access it.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(typeof window !== 'undefined') loadScript()
  }, [])
```

Or by adding it in each navigator statement:

```
Android: function () {
    return typeof window !== 'undefined' && navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
  },
  iOS: function () {
    return typeof window !== 'undefined' && 
 navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)
  },
  Windows: function () {
    return typeof window !== 'undefined' && 
 navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i)
  },
  any: function () {
    return typeof window !== 'undefined' &&  (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Windows())
  },
}
```

Of course, tweak it as you wish.

This workaround (`typeof window !== 'undefined'`) applies to all references to `window`, `document`, `navigator`, and other global objects unavailable in the SSR everywhere in your code.

---

Outside the scope of the question. It's extremely not recommended to avoid pointing the DOM like you are doing (with jQuery) in:

```
$('body').addClass('is-not-ios')
```

Really, don't do it.

With React, you are creating and manipulating a virtual DOM (vDOM) to avoid high-performance actions like the ones that manipulate the real DOM are. With React, you can use hooks ([`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)) or other workarounds to point to those elements within a React scope and environment.

Your approach will lead you to [hydration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/react-hydration/) issues because you are performing actions outside the scope of React. This means that you may face some rendering issues of some elements, especially when moving back and forward or when triggering some display actions.

---

> Do you know what can be my best approach in this kind of problem?

Yes, avoid using jQuery.

You can achieve the same behavior by creating a `useState` hook that changes its value depending on your `userAgent` logic to add a class.

For example:

```
const MasterIndexPage = props =>{
   const [userAgent, setUserAgent]=useState("");

   const detectUserAgent = ()=>{
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) setUserAgent("isAndroid");
   // and so on for the rest
   
   }

   useEffect(() => {
     detectUserAgent()
  }, [])
 
   return <main className={`${userAgent === "isAndroid" ? "someClassName" : ``}`}>
     <div
      id="menu-video"
      className="menu menu-box-bottom rounded-m"
      data-menu-height="410"
      data-menu-effect="menu-over"
    >
      <div class="responsive-iframe max-iframe">
        <iframe
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qCSBMbUa9jg"
          frameborder="0"
          allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
      </div>
      <div className="menu-title">
        <p className="color-highlight">Learn</p>
        <h1>How to install</h1>
        <a href="#" className="close-menu">
          <i className="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="content mt-n2">
        <p>Install Sparkle</p>
        <a
          href="#"
          className="close-menu btn btn-full btn-m shadow-l rounded-s text-uppercase font-600 bg-green-dark mt-n2"
        >
          Done
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <main>
}
```

To avoid extending the answer more than it actually is I've only added the Android workaround but the same logic applies to the rest. You can even add a function call inside the `className` to return the `userAgent` validation to avoid ternary conditions like `className={someFunctionThatReturnsTheClassname()}`. You can, of course, extend and isolate all this logic into separate functions even in a custom hook that fetches and returns the `userAgent` value.

Comment: Hello, I've tried the given solution. When I'm using gatsby build, it's still giving the navigator is not available during server side rendering. and is pointing out to  Android: function () {
> 3 |     return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
    |     ^
  4 |   },

Comment: Add `typeof window !== 'undefined' && navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)`. I've updated the answer. You'll need to add it to each statement. As I said, your approach will lead you to some caveats in the future, but if you still want to keep it, just add the condition in each `return` statement. In addition, you may be looking for `window.navigator` instead of directly `navigator`

Comment: Hello, I'm now encountering an error `WebpackError: ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. do I need to import $ from jquery? @Fer

Comment: That is was I was talking about. You have a mix of concepts, libraries, and dependencies. Yes, the `$` of the error stands for jQuery but you **can't** import it as an ES module (`import whatever from 'whatever'`) because jQuery is a completely different concept than React is, you'll need to add the script of the CDN manually to make the `$` available. Importing it in a React project makes no sense at all. You'll face hydration issues or other problems like the ones you are facing. Patching them is not the ideal solution

Comment: Do you know what can be my best approach in this kind of problem?

Comment: Yes, avoid using jQuery. You can do exactly the same without `$('body').addClass('is-not-ios')`. You just can add a React state that mutates it's value depending on the navigator value

Comment: hello do you know how can I add a pop up on my page load? so I can put on the install button if it's android, ios, or desktop

Comment: trying to test the userAgent on my Div. but it's not detecting my classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236378/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-pinky-promise).